# database is locked exception after use SQLite.ExecuteNonQuery function in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to do the following

```vb
Sub InsertData(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal conPath_ As String)

    Try
        Using con = New SQLiteConnection(conPath_)
            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(Sql, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd = Nothing
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Using this function, I am writing in a SQLite database, but I am getting the exception code

> database is locked

When I use this function to INSERT data to the table, I am having no problems, but when I am doing an UPDATE query, the program stops here, and after the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` the exception appears. It only says 'database is locked'

I have tried to execute the sql string that the function receives directly in the SQLite Studio, and I had no problems to update the value in the database, so the problem is not the query.

I don't know why this exception appears, because I am using the "Using - End using" structure, which must dispose the object.

Also, each time I call this function, I am creating a new instance of the connection, so I don't know why it says that the database is opened. Everytime I call this function, I open and close the database.

The weirdest thing, is that when the query is an INSERT, I never have problems executing this function, any times I need it, but when I am trying to UPDATE, the exception appears.

Sometimes it works the first time the program call this function using the UPDATE query, but only the first one, and this only a few times.

Maybe someone could see something that I cannot? Too many hours spent on this and for sure that is something very simple to fix.

Comment: The only way that method can work is if you are not using Parameters.  That is a bigger problem - especially with SQLite: you can trash your DB fairly easily in development.  Also, that command could/should be in a `Using` block as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Plutonix!

Finally I found the solution..

The problem was that I am doing different access to the database in my program. All of the functions that access to the database have the same structure:

```
Dim Sql As String = "SELECT NOMBRE FROM ROLE WHERE ID = '" & roleID_ & "'"
    Dim Cnx_SqLite As SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    Dim Cmd_SqLite As SQLite.SQLiteCommand
    Dim Dtr_SqLite As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader
    Try
        Cnx_SqLite = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(filePath)
        Cnx_SqLite.Open()
        Cmd_SqLite = New SQLiteCommand(Sql, Cnx_SqLite)
        Dtr_SqLite = Cmd_SqLite.ExecuteReader()

        If Dtr_SqLite.HasRows Then
            Dtr_SqLite.Read()
            roleName_ = Dtr_SqLite("NOMBRE")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Dtr_SqLite.Close()
    Dtr_SqLite = Nothing
    Cmd_SqLite.Cancel()
    Cmd_SqLite.Dispose()
    Cmd_SqLite = Nothing
    Cnx_SqLite.Close()
    Cnx_SqLite = Nothing
End Sub
```

The solution was to put the lines

```
Dtr_SqLite.Close()
```

and

```
Cmd_SqLite.Cancel()
```

With this two lines, the problem was solved.

I thought that this two functions are made internally, but it seems that it must be written in the code..

Finally the block I put at the beginning of my question looks like this:

```
 Sub InsertData(ByVal Sql As String, ByVal conPath_ As String)

    Try
        Using con = New SQLiteConnection(conPath_)
            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(Sql, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 20
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Cancel()
            cmd.Dispose()
            cmd = Nothing
            con.Close()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```